# Find common character in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find common chars in given list of strings without using collections library. Can someone help on this?

Input:

```
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]
```

Output:

```
result - ap
```

Comment: What would be result for ["abc", "bca"]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You example could have 3 interpretations: common char at any position, common chars at same position, or common chars at the beginning (all these would result in 'ap'):

To get common characters at any position, you can use a set intersection over all strings:

```
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]

common = set.intersection(*map(set,strings))

print(common) # {'p', 'a'}
```

To get common characters at the same positions:

```
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]

common = "".join(p for p,*r in zip(*strings) if all(p==c for c in r))

print(common) # ap
```

To get the longest common prefix (without libraries):

```
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]

common = next((strings[0][:i] for i,(p,*r) in enumerate(zip(*strings)) 
                              if any(p!=c for c in r)),min(strings,key=len))

print(common) # ap
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```py
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]

char_sets = [{*s} for s in strings]

result_set = char_sets[0]
for char_set in char_sets[1:]:
    result_set.intersection_update(char_set)

print(''.join(sorted(list(result_set))))
```

Returns:

```
ap
```

Assumed you need all common characters sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
print({c for c in strings[0] if all(c in s for s in strings[1:])})
```